# Global temperature maps

Tags: data, climate

Does anyone please knows where to get global surface temperature maps, yearly?
I need separate map for each year from 2002 to 2012 shows the average surface temperature over the globe, would be great if it is in GIS/Envi format.

Answer (score 1):

Unsure if you still need this data but a great resource for annual climate data is directly through NASA/USGS data repositories. Beyond that NCAR holds a large amount of gridded environmental data, specifically for climate/bioclimate. For specifically climate observations, you might be better off with HadCRU data. Both data sets are compatible with GIS software.

Historic Annual Precipitation and Temperature Grids: 
https://www.climatedataguide.ucar.edu/climate-data/global-land-precipitation-and-temperature-willmott-matsuura-university-delaware

Annual/Monthly Gridded Observed Records of Precipitation and Temperature Globally: http://www.metoffice.gov.uk/hadobs/hadcrut4/data/current/download.html